# how to move an image along circle in android?

Tags: android

I want to move my ball image in a circle or 360 degree, I have tried but it only draws ball image on canvas and not rotating in circle.

Can you please suggest feasible solution or give me some type of source code that can help me to move object in circle.

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    int cx = getWidth() / 2;
    int cy = getHeight() / 2;

    float angle = 5;
    float radius = 150;
    float x = (float) (cx + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180F) * radius);
    float y = (float) (cy + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180F) * radius);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, null);
    if (angle < 360) {

        angle += 5;
    }

    invalidate();

}
```

Comment: Each time when draw calls angle is assign 5 .. Put the angle variable outside draw

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DotsProgressbar  extends View {

    private Paint paint1;
    float angle = 5;
    float radius = 150;

    public DotsProgressbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }
    public DotsProgressbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DotsProgressbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs);
        init();
    }


    public void init(){

        // create the Paint and set its color
        paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);


        int cx = getWidth() / 2;
        int cy = getHeight() / 2;


        float x = (float) (cx + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180F) * radius);
        float y = (float) (cy + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180F) * radius);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, paint1);

        StartAnimation();
    }


    public void StartAnimation(){

        if (angle < 360) {

            angle += 5;
        }



        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                invalidate();
            }
        };new Handler().postDelayed(runnable,100);


    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//cos motion -> constant + cos(angle) * scalar. Sin motion is the same.
// Sin motion + cos motion = Circular motion
int constant = 250;
float angle = 0.05;
int scalar = 100;
float speed = 0.05;
```

put your for loop here...

```
   float x = constant + sin(angle) * scalar;
    float y = constant + cos(angle) * scalar;
    ellipse(x,y,50,50);
```

this [link](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/106191) may help to visualize my code..